# Retrieving Facebook check-ins to a particular Facebook page using Facebook webhooks subscription

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, webhooks, facebook-checkins

I have used Facebook webhooks to retrieve check-ins for a particular Facebook page that I have created. I have implemented an endpoint to receive the webhooks notifications. I was able to get the messages and posts by test users through the webhooks. However I cannot get any check-ins done for the page. Is there any special permissions or way to get the page check-ins?

Comment: Check-ins have been deprecated a while ago, in favor of normal posts with location information attached.

Comment: How were you able to "install" the webhook app on the Facebook page?

Comment: I second the question:  How were you able to "install" the webhook app on the Facebook page, particularly if you accomplished that using the webhooks GUI in Facebook for Developers?  Thanks!